# NULL Dictionary not evaluating to NULL

Tags: objective-c

I have a class which contains a dictionary used for making web calls. Basically the key value pairs are used to create the data that will be posted to the URL if the web call requires any values. This object class is set up using JSON.

I have a method which takes this class object and uses it to set up the web call. My problem is, if no parameters are required, then the dictionary is set to null which is fine, this is what I want, but for some reason when I do an if statement to check if the dictionary is null, it is hitting the else statement indicating that it is not null. Method looks like this

```
-(void)webCall :(WebServiceCall *)webCall_p
{

    //Creates a dictionary from the one stored in the WebResponse Class
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[webCall_p getWebServiceResponse] getVariablesByRegexMap];

    NSLog(@"%@", dict);
}
```

When I print it out I get this

```
<null>
```

Yet if I put in an if statement to check if it is null like so

```
 if(dict == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not NULL");
    }
```

It says not null. If I try to use the dict count command, like so

```
NSLog(@"%i", [dict count]);
```

The application crashes and brings up this error

> -[NSNull count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaf8678 2012-11-23 11:48:44.005 Testing[3403:14003] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull count]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0xaf8678'

I can't for the life of me figure this out. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently the value ist NSNull, which is an object, not nil. NSNull is a singleton `if (dict == NSNull)` should work.

Comment: This one works great, cheers. What I don't understand is why this is happening, for every other dictionary I have in my class, the usual dict == nil method works fine, or the [dict count] works, I am unsure as to why this particularly one calling count crashes the app

Comment: I don't know the details for this case but I can try explaining it in general. In some contexts an object must not be nil. For those cases the "empty" singleton object NSNull was introduced. It inherits from NSObject and therefore fulfills everything that a proper object has to do. But it is there to represent the value "nothing". If in doubt you need to get back to the related documentation or simply try it out. Most times you would deal with nil/null but sometimes NSNull comes handy.

Comment: My case is kinda complicated, I have quite a large framework I am creating using JSON, I just hadn't had this particular problem before, so I am unsure as to what I had done differently. I will have to do further tests on some of the other classes in my framework to see if the same thing occurs. Least I will know for future what to look out for if I encounter this error again, thanks again for information!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nil instead of NULL.

```
 if (dict == nil)
```

...

Comment: I have tried nil well, should have included that in my question, same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to check for existence - then check for `nil`, not `NULL`

```
if (dict) { // or (dict == nil) 
   // do something
}
```

Second, use correct formatter for `NSLog`, `%d` instead of `%i`.