# Check for Null values in CFDictionaryRef

Tags: objective-c

How do I check for a null value in a CFDictionaryRef?

I tested this code to check for a null value but it doesn't get any value.

```
CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex((addresses), i);



NSString * kCountry; 
if (dict != NULL && CFDictionaryContainsKey(dict, CFSTR("kABPersonAddressCountryKey")))
{
    kCountry = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, CFSTR("kABPersonAddressCountryKey"));
}
```

Comment: May be this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528602/null-dictionary-not-evaluating-to-null [ search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[objective-c]NULL+value ]

Comment: `if (kCountry == NULL)`, perhaps? It's probably bad form to have a variable name with a 'k' prefix, though. That's conventionally used to let the reader know it's a constant provided by a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up casting the CFDictionaryRef to a NSDictionary so I could call [dictionary objectForKey ... and check properly for nill values.

The code works when checking for nil values and not NULL values.

```
    if ([diction objectForKey:@"CountryCode"] == nil ||
        [[diction objectForKey:@"CountryCode"] isEqualToString:@""])
    {


    }else{

        kCountry = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, CFSTR("CountryCode"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you're asking or what you mean by "it doesn't get any value".

It is possible for `CFDictionary` to contains null values, which is different from `NSDictionary`. However, it's fairly improbable that any Apple API would provide a dictionary of that kind. In almost all cases, Apple APIs would return a dictionary of `CFType` objects, using the `kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks` callbacks that don't allow for null values. In particular, the dictionaries would be compatible with `NSDictionary`. I would assume that's the case unless the API is specifically documented to return some other kind of dictionary.

**IF** the dictionary you have received could have null values, the code you showed would work, resulting in `kCountry` being null if the dictionary contained a null value for the key `"kABPersonAddressCountryKey"`. If the dictionary doesn't contain that key, though, and you're not using ARC, then `kCountry` remains uninitialized after the `if` statement.

Also, I think you may be using the wrong key. You are passing a string object whose content is "kABPersonAddressCountryKey". However, `kABPersonAddressCountryKey` is not the content of a key. It's the identifier of a symbolic constant, which is a key. The content of that symbolic constant is likely different than its identifier.

Finally, if you're working with a dictionary that may contain null values, you should use `CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent()` to get the value if it's present and also return a boolean indicating if it was, all in one call. If that function returns true and stores a null value in the storage whose address you provide as the `value` argument, then the dictionary contained a null value. If it returns false, it didn't contain the key. If it returns true and a non-null value, well, that's the value it contained for the key.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to check for a null keys in a CFDictionaryRef. There will be null values because the data comes from the address book. Problem solved now.